# Kentico Document Query API - trying to match repeater results

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I have a `CMSRepeater` with `SelectOnlyPublished` set to `true`. In order to implement lazy loading, I have a webservice that loads more items for the repeater. The document queries I have tried (one at a time) are as follows:

```
var newsItems = tree.SelectNodes()
                .Types(pageTypes)
                .Path(path)
                .Where(whereStatement)
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
                .Page(page, count)
                .Columns(columns);

var newsItems = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
            .Types(pageTypes)
            .Path(path)
            .Where(whereStatement)
            .OrderBy(orderBy)
            .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
            .Page(page, count)
            .Published()
            .Columns(columns);
```

After inspecting the Sql queries generated by the repeater and the API, it seems the API is generating a bit of extra published checking in the where statement (removing this results in identical db results which would be my aim).

The extra where clause is:

```
DocumentCanBePublished] = 1 AND ([DocumentPublishFrom] IS NULL OR [DocumentPublishFrom] <= @Now) AND ([DocumentPublishTo] IS NULL OR [DocumentPublishTo] >= @Now
```

So my question is, how can I include this clause in the repeater? I want only published docs and would have thought the `SelectOnlyPublished=true;` on the repeater would be enough. I guess I could hardcode it into my WhereCondition but that doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox "Select only published" will generate the statement below in the background.

In your repeaters WHERE condition add this statement:

`([DocumentCanBePublished] = 1 AND ([DocumentPublishFrom] IS NULL OR [DocumentPublishFrom] <= GETDATE()) AND ([DocumentPublishTo] IS NULL OR [DocumentPublishTo] >= GETDATE()))`

You may think it's hard coding it but it's simply configuring a webpart.  If you want it more dynamic then use a macro within the WHERE condition to set the `GetDate()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Brenden Kehren. So what does the IsPublished=true; on a webpart do (if anything at all?)

Comment: Since DocumentPublishFrom and DocumentPublishTo default to null, does this mean that every new content page is treated as published by default?

Comment: If you do not have workflow turned on @oolong, yes, it will be published by default when you click save.  If you have workflow turned on, it will go through the workflow process.  Your workflow can define if it will auto-publish or require you to click a button to publish after you've made your changes.

Comment: @BrendenKehren Thanks Brenden. Using workflow was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.